# How can I calculate the differences between now date and constant date. And edit it like 1d,1m,1w

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I want to show the transaction history on my project. But I want to show like transaction was 2m ago or 2h ago. For this reason how can I calculate and control this date calculation.

The variable came like
`dd/mm/yyy hh:mm:ss`

I want to show like after calculation
`1m`
`1d`

Comment: var now = moment('31/8/2019 11:30:00', 'DD/MM/YYYY hh:mm:ss').fromNow();

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would recommend moment.js to you [moment.js docs - difference](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/displaying/difference/)

```
const date1 = moment('2016-10-08 10:29:23');
const date2 = moment('2016-10-08 11:06:55');
const diff = date2.diff(date1);
const minutesDif= date2.diff(date1, 'minutes');
```

for your exact application i would recommend a look into the documentation

Comment: When I try run 'npm install moment' it doesn't work getting error to me is there any alternative like this ?

Comment: Maybe show the error or your code?